# Debugging fetch operations in next.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, next.js

So I want to debug my next.js app. Problem is a big part will not debug. So I added the chrome attached debugger (in launch.json):

```
        {
        "type": "pwa-chrome",
        "request": "launch",
        "name": "Launch Chrome against localhost",
        "url": "http://localhost:3010",
        "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}"
    }
```

So the way I use this is I run in a terminal: "npm run dev" and then press F5 in vscode.
This works partially as the react components & next.js pages will be debugged. The problem is the fetch calls with [getStaticProps()](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching) will not.

So I looked in the docs of next.js and [there](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/debugging) it is written, use script like:
"dev": "NODE_OPTIONS='--inspect' next dev"
When I then run next in the terminal with: "npm run dev" I get a build error: *the command "NODE_OPTIONS" is either written wrong or could not be found.*

So how can I debugg these next.js functions like getStaticProps() ?
Also should I write an issue-ticket to next.js?

Edit: It should also mention that the API is a asp.net core API, not a next.js API.

Edit 2: Well now I am bypassing this problem by using the [SWR](https://swr.vercel.app/) package.

Comment: `getStaticProps`/`getStatcPath`/`getServerSideProps` all run on the server, as such any output from them will be available on the terminal you started the server on, not on the browser/debugger console.

Comment: @juliomalves I know that. That is were the 2. part with "NODE_OPTIONS='--inspect' next dev" comes into play. The problem is, it just doesn't work.

Comment: One quick and dirty solution is to append the debug value to returned props `return: { props: { post, debugValue }} `and then log it inside the React component which receives that prop (might not cover all cases).

Answer (score 1):

I think you can leverage [Preview Mode](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/preview-mode). It renders the pages at request time instead of build time so that your debugger / logs should work. You have to update your `getStaticProps` function to use `context.preview` in order for it to work:

```
export async function getStaticProps(context) {
  // If context.preview is true, append "/preview" to the API endpoint
  // to request draft data instead of published data. This will vary
  // based on which headless CMS you're using.
  const res = await fetch(`https://.../${context.preview ? 'preview' : ''}`)
  // ...
}
```